# Get raw stacktrace from Firebase crash reporting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Recently I have a published obfuscated Android app with firebase crash reporting enabled. App once crashes and since I haven't uploaded mapping file I cannot read stacktrace properly.

So I wanted to download stack trace and deobfuscate it manually with `/retrace.sh -verbose mapping.txt ~/trace.txt`

However I'm unable to get raw form of stacktrace...

So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I get raw form from firebase crash reporting tab on their site?
2. How can I upload mapping file before publishing app into play store?

Comment: can you post an example of your manually copied stack trace from firebase crash reporting? I can answer both of your questions

Comment: If you want this ability to copy stack traces from the Firebase Crash Reporting console, please also make a feature request for it.  Every report matters: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Currently, there's no way to get raw stack traces from Firebase Crash Reporting. So you need to copy them manually when viewing the detail of each error.

The problem is the deobfuscation doesn't work with that stack trace string copied from Firebase Crash Reporting, It's because of the missing **at** statement at the beginning of each line of the stack trace.

For example, this is what you get from Firebase Crash Reporting

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.models.User.getUserName()' on a null object reference
com.example.views.adapters.ExampleAdapter.a (SourceFile:110)
com.example.views.adapters.ExampleAdapter.a (SourceFile:31)
b.a.a.a.b.a (SourceFile:54)
b.a.a.a.b.a (SourceFile:54)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.a (SourceFile:6279)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.b (SourceFile:6312)
```

You just need to add **at** at the beginning of each line that contains `SourceFile` string. The result should look like this

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.models.User.getUserName()' on a null object reference
at com.example.views.adapters.ExampleAdapter.a (SourceFile:110)
at com.example.views.adapters.ExampleAdapter.a (SourceFile:31)
at b.a.a.a.b.a (SourceFile:54)
at b.a.a.a.b.a (SourceFile:54)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.a (SourceFile:6279)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.b (SourceFile:6312)
```

With this new string, you should be able to deobfuscate the stack trace as usual.

I know, that's a lot of work especially when there are multiple errors occurred but this is the current workaround until the Firebase Crash Reporting team decided to enable a feature to download raw stack traces or just put the **at** string at the details instead of trimming that out.

2. Firebase team just recently released a Crash Reporting plugin for this purpose. [The guide is here - Uploading ProGuard mapping files with Gradle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#uploading_proguard_mapping_files_with_gradle)

Honestly, I haven't been able to enable this plugin successfully, still confused by the guide. I really hope they will make it as simple as in Fabric Crashlytics, by just adding `ext.enableCrashlytics = true` in the `build.gradle` file.

There's also another way, by purposely crashing the app before release, then generate a new release APK without the error, and then you can upload the `mapping.txt` file to Firebase Crash Reporting console. :)

Comment: Nice and quick answer thanks. I'll wait whether somebody can find other way to get the raw stacktrace, but I think I there is no other way. I'll do it by guide you suggested...

Comment: Worked, thanks! I still can't deobfuscate the very first line of crash, but it is still much better than nothing: `Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void xxx.h.i.b$d.r()' on a null object reference`. Do you have additional insights about this very first line?

Comment: @Vasiliy, ah sorry, I also can't deobfuscate that first line :/ but you should already know where the problem is just by looking the lines at under that line.